# Can basement plumbing rough-in be moved to a new location in the crawl space?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, crawlspace

Thanks for any help with these Plumbing 101 questions. Before talking with a pro about bathroom updates, I want a good grasp of what might be feasible.

This bathroom has water and drain coming up through the floor (in the corner, adjacent walls are exterior). Crawl space below, balcony above. 100 year old house. The space was originally a back porch and has long since been enclosed and turned into a bathroom. Will edit with a pic soon.

In theory, can the plumbing be redirected in the crawl space to come up through the floor at a new location a couple feet away? Alternatively, would a chase built out from the wall to house plumbing be a smarter choice, and if so, what approximate depth would the chase need to be?

Comment: These are a lot of different questions, though related. 1 - A picture of the existing bathroom would help quite a bit. A picture of the crawlspace too if that's not too hard to do. 2 - Most of this is on-topic for DIY SE, but "attractive pipes break the bank" is a bit of an opinion piece (both on what defines "attractive" and what defines "break the bank") so that might be best left out. 3 - Rules do vary somewhat, so location (city/state/country) may be helpful.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask page](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: why don't you simply call several contractors and request a quote for the job from each one .... discuss what is, or is not, feasible with them

Comment: Yep, we will definitely be doing that further down the road. Right now we still have a lot of research to do first.

Comment: Sorry, but this is still too broad. The only appropriate answer is "probably" to the first part and "as deep as it needs to be" for the second.

Comment: @jsotola Contractors are often one of (a) hard to get out to give a quote, (b) quote sky-high figuring once in a while they'll get a bite but basically "ridiculous", (c) give too many unkowns because they either honestly don't know how bad things will be until they start the project **or** they don't want to take the time to research the specifics. So I'm with OP on "research first". A good plumber should be able to give a quick answer because all they do is plumbing, but a good plumber is often hard to find, and may (legitimately) want to charge just to look.